# How to find a word in a colum

Tags: r

I have code to get Y or N in a new column, if ‘Keywords’ contains ‘Complete’ (if possible also variation of the word such as complete, Complet) then Y, else N.
My problem is that, when the word in on higher case or separated by "," "/" or "-" the code do not work. Can you help ?

```
id_base_full$Completion.Flag <- 0

x <- nrow(id_base_full)

for(i in 1:x){

  if (grepl("Complete",id_base_full$HI.Keywords[i])){
    id_base_full$Completion.Flag[i] <- "Y"
  }else if (grepl("complete",id_base_full$HI.Keywords[i])){
    id_base_full$Completion.Flag[i] <- "Y"
  }else if (grepl("Complet" ,id_base_full$HI.Keywords[i])){
    id_base_full$Completion.Flag[i] <- "Y"
  }else{ 
    id_base_full$Completion.Flag[i] <- "N" 
  }
  next [i]
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `?grepl` help page. You can set `ignore.case = TRUE` to match upper or lower case. As far as *'separated by "," "/" or "-"'* I do not know what you mean. Can you show examples of sample input and desired output?

Comment: Would you mind sharing a sample dataset ? something like `dput(head(id_base_full))` taking care there is your problematic cases in the resulting set

Comment: Also, `grepl` is vectorized so you don't need a `for` loop - it can operate on the whole column all at once.

Comment: Make a very simple data set as an example, not a full one. If you are saying that the word has a ",", "/" or "-"  at the beginning or end you might try fixed=TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should achieve what you want:

```
id_base_full$Completion.Flag <- "N"
id_base_full$Completion.Flag[grepl("complete?", ignore.case=TRUE, id_base_full$HI.Keywords)] <- "Y"
```

The idea is to create the column with "N" everywhere and then for the rows where the word complet (with an optional e at end) is found set the value to "Y".

In regex the `?` means 0 or 1 occurrence of the preceding character (e here), grepl will return a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE allowing to select the proper rows.

To be more straightforward than Y/N, I'd keep the Boolean values in the resulting dataset with:

```
id_base_full$Completion.Flag <- grepl("complete?", ignore.case=TRUE, id_base_full$HI.Keywords)
```